# Any way to detect `UnsafeMutablePointer` has been deallocated?

Tags: ios, swift

I got a custom observer which is checking if changes have been made to objects it is observing. The object holds reference to the original property (pointer) in an `UnsafeMutablePointer` ... the problem is that all works jolly good unless the original value deallocates and I start getting random values from whatever now occupies that bit of memory ...
Is there any way to detect the original object is gone so I can invalidate my observer?

Edit: To make clear what I am trying to achieve I have added my current implementation (which kinda works for local class variables):

```swift
class Observer<Observed> where Observed: Equatable {

    typealias Binder = ((Observed) -> ())
    typealias Storage = UnsafeMutablePointer<Observed>

    private var storage: Storage

    private var bind: Binder

    private var running: Bool

    init(_ value: Storage, binder: @escaping Binder) {
        storage = value
        bind = binder
        running = true

        var val: Observed = value.pointee
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            while self.running {
                if val != value.pointee {
                    self.bind(value.pointee)
                    val = value.pointee
                }
            }
        }
    }

    var value: Observed {
        return storage.pointee
    }

    deinit {
        running = false
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

No; it is your responsibility to ensure that an unsafe pointer cannot outlive its referenced object. ("Important memory details are your problem" is what Swift generally means by the "Unsafe" designation.)

Generally the correct tool here is a `weak` reference rather than a pointer.

---

Your observation code is incorrect in numerous ways. The basic approach of a tight loop that reads the value and compares it to an existing value is going to drain battery very quickly even if it had no other problems. It's also invalid because your pointee isn't thread-safe. You can't read it on a random thread and be promised a coherent value.

Swift doesn't promise that value types stay at the same place in memory, so even if the value still "exists," your pointer is not promised to point to it. It doesn't even promise that value types have a heap (i.e. persistent) memory location; they may be stored on the stack or even in registers. When you take a pointer to it, it may create a temporary copy in order to provide a memory location, but it's not promised to be the same memory as other references to it. That's the whole point of a value type. It can be freely copied and moved around (and even entirely optimized away in some cases). If you need to be able to **refer** to the instance, then you need a **refer**ence type.

Comment: But I can not keep a weak reference on a struct (which means any primitive)

Comment: You can't safely hold onto a pointer to a struct either (outside of a `withUnsafe...Pointer` block). Structs are value types. I suspect your current code is undefined behavior.

Comment: I have updated the question with example code, thank you very much for your input so far!!

Comment: What you've written here is not defined behavior. You can't do this in Swift. Value types (structs) don't support this kind of observation. They don't have identity. If you want to observe something, that "something" has to have an identity (it needs to be possible to tell the difference between two "somethings" that are equal). That requires, in Swift, a reference type.

Comment: There's a reason that the new ObservableObject protocol in Combine requires conformance to AnyObject (i.e. that it is a reference type). That wasn't an accident. it's a requirement of observation.